# how to read html file data as array in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

My 1 file is city.html which contains the following code

```
<script language="javascript">alert("Page Called"); </script>
'Bhubaneshwar', 'Orissa', 'India'
```

My another file index.php contains the following code

```
$x=file_get_contents("city.html");
$x=array($x);
echo $x[0];
```

It shows the following output 
'Bhubaneshwar', 'Orissa', 'India'

But I want single word output like this.

When I print `$x[0]`, it should be `Bhubaneshwar`

When I print `$x[1]`, it should be `Orissa`

When I print `$x[2]`, it should be `India`

Comment: Maybe elaborate on what is happening as I assume it's not what you want...

Comment: Use explode and do this. $x = explode(',',$x[0]);

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to use double quotes instead of single quotes in the HTML file?

Comment: Use explode and do this. $x = explode(',',$x[0]);sdfsdf

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert string to array:-

```
// Remove script tag
$string = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $x);  
// $string = str_replace(' ', '', $string); // Remove space from string
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string); // Remove whitespace from string
// explode string 
$x = explode(',',$string);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @RayonDabre: Yes I have missed it. Is it okay now?

Comment: Wow, this removes all spaces in whatever words are in the list.

Comment: @trincot: Yes I am getting you. I need to remove just whitespace.

Comment: Good, but I still get the script inside the first element of the result array... Have a look at some of the other answers.

Comment: I assume that he wrote script tag for debugging purpose but if it is there then It will also remove from updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$x=file_get_contents("city.html");
$x=array($x);
$html = preg_replace('#<script[^>]*?.*?</script>#', '', $x);
$str = str_replace(', ', ',', $html);
$x = explode(',',trim($str[0]));
$remove[] = "'";
$result = str_replace( $remove, "", $x );
foreach($result as $cities)
{
   echo $cities . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: This does not remove the script tag from the result.

Comment: Yep, exactly the same as @RaviHirani did. Once I have finished commenting on all answers, you'll all have the same code. :-)

Comment: @trincot code has been updated & have different way! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that first removes the preceding script tag(s) and breaks down the remainder into an array:

```
$x=array_pop(explode('</script>', $x));
$x=preg_split("/'\s*,\s*'/", trim(trim($x), "'"));
```

The first of those two statements is only needed if you keep that script tag inside your HTML, which seems to be there for testing only.

To display the result, you could do this:

```
foreach($x as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

Output:

> Bhubaneshwar
>   Orissa
>   India

#### Considerations

It is unusual to have such data format inside HTML files. HTML is intended for rendering data in a user-friendly manner, and that representation does not really fit.

If you are the creator of the HTML file, then consider moving to a [JSON](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. In that case your file would be named `city.json` and would have this content (the double quotes and brackets are required):

```
["Bhubaneshwar", "Orissa", "India"]
```

And the code would make use of JSON functions like this:

```
$json=file_get_contents("city.json");
$x=json_decode($json);
```

This way you really use standards, and the code is compact.

You could again display the contents of *$x* like before:

```
foreach($x as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

Output:

> Bhubaneshwar
>   Orissa
>   India

If you are the creator of that file, and use PHP to create it, then make use of JSON functions as well, as follows:

```
$x = array("Bhubaneshwar", "Orissa", "India");
file_put_contents ("city.json", json_encode($x));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove script tags

```
$x = file_get_contents("city.html");
$x = preg_replace('%<script[^>]*>.*?</script>%/m', '', $x);
```

and then you can use explode:

```
$array = explode(',', $x);
```

then you can trim and remove quotes:

```
$array = array_map(function($item) {
   return preg_replace("/^'|'$/", trim($item));
}, $array);
```